# Refiner webpart shows duplicate users

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, refiner, duplicate

In a search refinement webpart we have mapped a refinableString as a refiner. This managed property is mapped to one crawled property named "ows_contactPerson"

Unfortunately, we're getting duplicate user names in the refiner. Let's assume User A. In "ows_contactPerson" user A can exist as a single entry or be a part of a collection of users.

So the refiner would look something like

User 1
User 2
**User A**
User 3
**User A**, User B
User 4
**User A**, User B, User C

Is there a possibility to make User A show up only once in the refiner?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, there is no OOTB method to make User A show up only once in the refiner.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry... The refiner sees each result as a unique entry... Not possible to split them apart. Same issue with MMS fields